# $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(z+1-i)^n}{3^nn^2}\right)$ and the ratio test

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I'm given the example of 
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{(z+1-i)^n}{3^nn^2}\right)$$

The book tells me that using ratio test we get

$$p = \lim_{n\to\infty} \left|\frac{z+1-i}{3} * \frac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}\right| = |\frac{z+1-i}{3}|$$

How the heck did the book get that answer for the ratio test on that example? I got a completely different answer. I don't understand how they were able to bring the $n^2$ to the numerator or any part of the $n^2/((n+1)^2)$

Comment: Let $a_m = \dfrac{(z+1-i)^m}{3^m m^2}$. Then what is $\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$?

Comment: Did you purposely change $n$ to $m$? I calculated $an+1/an$ and got a very different answer from the book.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to get is the convergence radius, then Cauchy-Hadamard formula works really nice here:

$$\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\frac1{3^nn^2}}=\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac1{3\sqrt[n]{n^2}}=\frac13\implies R=3$$

and we get (absolute if you want) convergence in the disk $\;|z+1-i|<3\;$ .

Comment: Why are you able to pull out $z+1-i$?

Comment: Not an answer to the question.

Comment: You answer do not have $z+1-i$ in the limit. It seems odd that you can just pull it out.

Comment: @KurtE If you're doing a little complex analysis is because, I hope and I think, you already did real analysis. You should have seen Cauchy Hadamard to calculate a power series' convergence interval. If not...too bad, but you can google it. It **only depends** on the series' coefficients, that's why it obviously has not $\;z+1-i\;$ ...!

Answer (score 0):

> How the heck did the book get that answer for the ratio test on that example?

Do you understand what is [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)?

The usual form of the test makes use of the limit

$$
{\displaystyle L=\lim _{n\to \infty }\left|{\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}}\right|.}
$$
Now what are the $a_n$'s in your series?

> I don't understand how they were able to bring the $n^2$ to the numerator or any part of the $n^2/((n+1)^2)$.

For a simpler version of your question, do you know how to use the ratio test to show that 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{3^nn^2}<\infty?
$$

Comment: I calculated using $an+1 / an$ and I got $pn = |(z+1-i)/3(n+1)|$ That doesn't look even close to the answer the book wants me to have.

Comment: Then you either got you $a_n$ wrong or there is a miscalculation in the ratio $a_{n+1}/a_n$.

Comment: Ah, that must be it. I have never seen the ratio test used like that one the bottom-most equation you have. Where did the $z+1-i$ go when you did that?